# How does the use of concave mirror over plane mirror advantageous in the Fizeau method of determination of speed of light?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, speed-of-light, reflection, geometric-optics

The following text is from *Concepts of Physics* by Dr. H.C.Verma, from the chapter "Speed of Light", page 445, topic "Fizeau Method":

> [image]
>
> One can use a concave mirror in place of the plane mirror [$M$]. If the radius of curvature of this mirror be equal to its distance from the convex lens $L_3$ (i.e., equal to the focal length of $L_3$), a slight error in orientation of lens $L_3$ does not seriously affect the accuracy of the experiment.

I think when the lens is tilted, the parallel beam of light will get focussed on the focal plane (and not the focus) which is a plane perpendicular to the principal axis passing through the focus. If so, a plane mirror will suffice. Then, how does the use of concave mirror over plane mirror advantageous in this experiment?

Will the concave mirror be beneficial if there is an error in orientation of the lens $L_2$? First of all, in an experiment requiring a good amount of accuracy why does an experimenter wish to induce errors while placing the lenses and then use some other method to correct the errors?

Comment: This might have to do with [field curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petzval_field_curvature) : " the image 'plane' (the arc) deviates from a flat surface (the vertical line)".

Comment: [Also](https://www.microscopyu.com/tutorials/curvatureoffield).

Comment: @KeithMcClary: Thank you for sharing the links. They were useful. This statement is from the second one - "_The nominal curvature of this surface is the reciprocal of the lens radius..._". But in the quoted text in the question the radius of curvature of the concave mirror is said to be equal to the focal length of the lens, but not reciprocal of the lens radius as given in the second link. I understand that field curvature takes place, but why is the curvature of the mirror different for the case in the question and that in the source?